# Change ubuntu 16.04 text in login

Tags: text

I am currently compiling an Ubuntu 16.04 however I want to change the text 'Ubuntu 16.04' to 'FT Linux v1.0' as I'm trying to get rid of all ubuntu traces for my distro. As of now I'm compiling the distro but I hope to get a answer on how to mod the text in the login screen saying 'Ubuntu 16.04 LTS' Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this message by editing the `/etc/issue` and `/etc/issue.net`.

- [Customizing your Logon with /etc/issue](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/logon.html)

Comment: Your answer while helpful will become useless if/when the link is no longer active and for that reason it would be better to include essential parts of the answer here and use the link as a reference. Please refer to: http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer  Thank you for helping improve the site!

Comment: @ElderGeek "Edit `/etc/issue`" is a sufficient and complete answer to **that question**.  Questioner will reach the goal by simply editing a few letters of the `/etc/ issue`.  I think that there is no need for all of the answer is in reference to cover specification. However, if you write a different answer, I will learn from your answer.

Comment: Assuming of course that the OP  knows how to edit those files (which based on a number of questions I've seen here may not be true.) I try to create answers that even a completely inexperienced user can follow as this has a tendency to reduce the number of messages I get in my inbox asking how to do basic tasks. Perhaps your results will differ.

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable here, please read http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer, if you don't improve this answer, it will be removed.